# Unable to run vbscript from php using exec

Tags: php, vbscript, cmd, exec

Am trying to run the following code through php.

My aim is to run the vbscript file named sample.vbs from php using exec function.

But it seems that this approach is not working.

I am not sure if its a coding issue or permission related issue.

The vbscript runs fine when doubled clicked on it or when i manually run it through 
the command prompt.

The vbscript is a simple code that opens IE and navigates to google.com

This is my php script

```
<?php
echo 'who am i : '. exec("whoami");
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
echo '<br/><br/>';
echo "cscript C:\\www\\testiefail\\sample.vbs";
echo '<br/><br/>';

exec("cscript C:\\www\\testiefail\\sample.vbs", $output, $error_flag); 

if ($error_flag) {
   print_r('error_flag : ' . $error_flag);
   echo '<br/><br/>';
} else {
   print_r('success : '.$error_flag);
   echo '<br/><br/>';   
}

/*
Output as Follows
==================
who am i : server\administrator

Current script owner: Administrator

cscript C:\www\testiefail\sample.vbs

success : 0

*/

?>
```

My vbscript is as follows

```
'******************************************************************
'  Set the URL that will open in the IE Window
'******************************************************************
StrURL = "https://www.google.co.in/"

Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objExplorer.visible = 0
'******************************************************************
'Set IE parameters
'******************************************************************
objExplorer.Toolbar = 1
objExplorer.StatusBar = 1 
objExplorer.FullScreen = False

objExplorer.navigate(strURL)

'******************************************************************
'Wait for IE to finish loading the URL
'******************************************************************
Do While objExplorer.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 2000   'Sleep added to reduce CPU spike issues
Loop

'******************************************************************
'Show IE Window Now
'******************************************************************
objExplorer.visible = 1
```

Yep thats all related with codes, It just doesnt work when tried to execute via php.

And i am out of ideas.

Please help me......

Thankyou.